# FCM Notifications are not working after 5 minutes of mobile lock. Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending notifications with this method.

```
   sendVoicePushNotification({required userToken,required String currentName,required String voiceUrl}) async {
try {
  print("user token is: $userToken");
  final body = {
    "to": userToken,
    "notification": {
      "title": currentName,
      "body": 'New voice message',
      "android_channel_id": "voice",
    },
    'android': {
      'priority': 'high',
    },
    'data':{
      'type':'voice',
      'id':'1234',
      'voiceUrl': voiceUrl
    }
  };
  var res = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;char=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'key=' },
      body: jsonEncode(body)
  );
  print('status: ${res.statusCode}');
  print('res body: ${res.body}');
} catch (e) {
  print('sendPushNotificationE: $e');
}}
```

And Receiving background notifications with this code. onBackgroundMessage method is in main method of app.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {}
```

When I terminate app, notification receives. After lock screen, first 5 minutes notification receives but then nothing. When I unlock app, again notification receive.
I have all necessary permissions like: run in background, notification permission, notifications on lock screen.
I hope you understand!

Answer (score 1):

According to Firebase docs, and how I implemented this days ago:

> Handle background messages by registering a onBackgroundMessage
> handler. When messages are received, an isolate is spawned (Android
> only, iOS/macOS does not require a separate isolate) allowing you to
> handle messages even when your application is not running.
>
> There are a few things to keep in mind about your background message
> handler:
>
> It must not be an anonymous function. It must be a top-level function
> (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization). When using
> Flutter version 3.3.0 or higher, the message handler must be annotated
> with `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` right above the function declaration
> (otherwise it may be removed during tree shaking for release mode).
>
> ```
> @pragma('vm:entry-point') Future<void>
> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {   // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background,
> such as Firestore,   // make sure you call `initializeApp` before
> using other Firebase services.   await Firebase.initializeApp();
>
>   print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}"); }
>
> void main() {  
> FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
> runApp(MyApp()); }
> ```

Please follow [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#background_messages) to learn more.

Also it's good to mention [Don't kill my app](https://dontkillmyapp.com/). Some OEMs have very strict and aggressive battery saving scheduling algorithms that kill apps in the background to the point that app notifications are received later than when they were sent. Unfortunately there's no way around this issue on Android devices except excluding your app from battery optimisations on [phone Settings](https://www.tac.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/621456/How-to-disable-the-battery-optimization-on-Android-ammended-for-web-DPY-002.pdf).